# Proper way to set a child item property in QML

Tags: qt, qml

Everyone knows about how to set a background for Buttons, Popups etc via the background property of these elements. But I am wondering, how can I create such a property myself for my own custom elements? I found a way but it looks pretty ugly and I can't seem to find the qml code for Button, Popup etc where said property is defined. So i played a bit and came up with the idea of using Bindings like this:

```
Item {
    id: root
    property Item background: Rectangle {
        color: "red"
    }
    Binding {
        target: root.background
        property: "parent"
        value: root
    }
    Binding {
        target: root.background
        property: "anchors.fill"
        value: root
        when: root.background.parent == root
        delayed: true
    }
}
```

As mentioned that looks pretty tiresome if you need to declare a lot of properties of the child. So, how does Qt do it or what is the proper way of doing it?

Comment: If you're looking for where a Button's `background` property is defined, it's in C++ code. A Button derives from AbstractButton, which derives from Control. You can find the Control's `background` property declared [here](https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols2/blob/5.15/src/quicktemplates2/qquickcontrol_p.h).

Comment: I was actually looking for the qml declaration if such a thing exists since I am interested in the qml way of doing it. But thank you nonetheless!

Comment: As I said, in QQC2 source, the property is defined in C++, not qml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// ItemWithBackground.qml
Item {
    property alias background: backgroundLoader.sourceComponent

    Loader {
        id: backgroundLoader
        anchors { fill: parent }
        sourceComponent: Rectangle { color: 'red' } // default background implementation 
    }
}

// Usage example:
ItemWithBackground {
    background: Rectangle {
        color: 'green'
    }
}
```

Comment: I didnt think of using the Loader like this. But it makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Tanzmaus Note that the QML way of doing what's done in Qt Quick Controls 2 is indeed what you actually posted in your question. It's not very practical having to define multiple Binding objects though. QQC2 do it in C++. Using a Loader like mentioned here changes the semantics, the green Rectangle is now a Component and not an instance of an Item. For example if you specify an id for it, you can't access outside its scope. And you also can't access the background as an Item. `myRect.color = "orange"` won't work, same for `background.visible = false`. Also it creates one more `QQuickItem`.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re on a recent Qt version, have a look at using inline components. They allow you to create API’s like this easily.